# ETL kettle:Unable to find info row set for step 'FieldSelection'

Tags: etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon

My kettle has this error: "Java Code.0 - Unable to find info row set for step 'FieldSelection'", the location of the error is the Java script, the previous step of the Java script is the field selection step, I did not find any relevant solutions on the web, Can you tell me what might be the reason for this?

I can't find any solution using bing search, how can I find out the cause of the problem or solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide full log and the code you are executing in PDI. This question doesn't have enough details to provide a solution.